# Handling errors in a loop gracefully

Tags: c++, qt, exception

I am traversing a list and converting each item in the list (a file name). If there were no errors, I display green icon for the file otherwise red. My code below has a little too much logic to track this, could it be better?

```
for(int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
{
    ......

    int allConverted = 0;

    try
    {
        convertFile( file, dest1)

        allConverted++;
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error err)
    {
        item->setIcon( QIcon("c:/code/Red.ico"));

        QMessageBox::information(this, APP_NAME, err.what(), QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::Abort) == QMessageBox::Abort);
    }

    try
    {
        convertFile( file, dest2)

        allConverted++;
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error err)
    {
        item->setIcon( QIcon("c:/code/Red.ico"));

        QMessageBox::info(this, APP_NAME, err.what(), QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::Abort) == QMessageBox::Abort);

    }

    if (allConverted >= 2)
        item->setIcon( QIcon("c:/code/Green.ico"));

}
```

Comment: Edit: you are repeating the (convertFile...allConverted...trycatch) that in my opinion screams for a cicle wrapped in a single try/catch statement

Comment: I still have to run the loop, I only need to mark certain items accordingly if there were errors on them.

Comment: moreover you can collapse the allConverted++ and if(allconv etc as: if (++allConverted >= 2)
        item->setIcon( QIcon("c:/code/Green.ico"));

Comment: Catch exceptions by reference. They may be polymorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to attempt the second `convertFile` even when the first call fails? If that is what is intended, then something like this would be cleaner:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {

    bool success = true;

    try {
        convertFile(file, dest1);
    }
    catch(const std::runtime_error& err) {
        success = false;
        QMessageBox::information(this, APP_NAME, err.what(), QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::Abort) == QMessageBox::Abort);
    }

    try {
        convertFile(file, dest2);
    }
    catch(const std::runtime_error& err) {
        success = false;
        QMessageBox::info(this, APP_NAME, err.what(), QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::Abort) == QMessageBox::Abort);
    }

    if (success) {
        item->setIcon(QIcon("c:/code/Green.ico"));
    }
    else {
        item->setIcon(QIcon("c:/code/Red.ico"));
    }
}
```

Otherwise, it could be simplified to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
    try {
        convertFile(file, dest1);
        convertFile(file, dest2);
        item->setIcon(QIcon("c:/code/Green.ico"));
    }
    catch(const std::runtime_error& err) {
        item->setIcon(QIcon("c:/code/Red.ico"));
        QMessageBox::information(this, APP_NAME, err.what(), QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::Abort) == QMessageBox::Abort);
    }
}
```

On a side note, exceptions should generally be caught by const reference (which I have illustrated here), in order to account for polymorphic hierarchy.

Comment: If both convertFile() s fail, don't you lose the err.what() of the first fail?

Comment: @MichaelVincent Hmm, what do you mean by that? The scope of `err` is limited by the try-catch blocks, so where else would you want to be using it?

Comment: The first give me correct result and is better than my post. I also like the fact that if any of the two `convertFile`fails, it will display the warning icon which is good.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
{
    bool anyErrors = false;

    try
    {
        convertFile( file, dest1)
        convertFile( file, dest2)
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error err)
    {
        anyErrors = true;
    }

    if (anyErrors)
    {
        item->setIcon( QIcon("c:/code/Red.ico"));
        QMessageBox::information(this, APP_NAME, err.what(), QMessageBox::Ok, QMessageBox::Abort) == QMessageBox::Abort);
    }
    else        
        item->setIcon( QIcon("c:/code/Green.ico"));
```

Comment: If convertFile( file, dest1 fails, convertFile() for dest2 is not executed.  Unlike the source in the question.